# Cannot source file using find, fzf, and xargs

Tags: find, xargs, source, virtualenv, fzf

I am trying to use fzf to select and activate different virtual environments. However, I am receiving the follow error:
`xargs: source: No such file or directory`

My command comprises three parts: `find | fzf | xargs`
 (1) find locates my virtual environments,
 (2) a virtual environment is selected using fzf, and 
 (3) xargs is used to `source` the selected file.

Below is the full command:
`find ~/.virtualenvs/ -maxdepth 1 -type d | fzf | xargs -I {} source {}/bin/activate`
`xargs: source: No such file or directory`

I can directly source the file (i.e., command prompt shows entry into fzf_delete virtual environment):
`brian:~$ source /home/brian/.virtualenvs/fzf_delete/bin/activate`
`(fzf_delete) brian:~$`

I can select the virtual environment using fzf:
`find ~/.virtualenvs/ -maxdepth 1 -type d | fzf`
`/home/brian/.virtualenvs/fzf_delete`

I have also isolated the issue to xargs by removing the dependency on find and fzf:
`echo "/home/brian/.virtualenvs/fzf_delete" | xargs -I {} source {}/bin/activate`
`xargs: source: No such file or directory`

I have tried every variation of quoting, use of variables, string concatenation, command substitution, using bash -c, etc. that I can think of to no avail.
**How can I get xargs to source the selected file?**

PS - I am aware that null termination should be used with find, fzf, and xargs in case file names contain spaces, but that does not appear to be causing the immediate issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`source` is a shell built-in command. You're not going to be able to run with `xargs`, because `xargs` can't make changes to your current shell. That is, even if you were to do something like `... | xargs -I {} sh -c 'source {}/bin/activate'` it wouldn't help, because:

1. Your current shell spawns xargs
2. xargs spawns a new shell
3. The new shell sources your file
4. The new shell exits
5. xargs exits

And you're back where you started with no modifications to your environment.

---

On the other hand, this would work:

```
source "$(find ~/.virtualenvs/ -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 | fzf --read0)"/bin/activate
```

Note that for the same reason you can't use `xargs`, you also can't run the above command via a shell script. That is, if you create `$HOME/bin/select-venv` with that command and make it executable, it won't work because it will spawn in a subshell.

You *can*, however, create a `select_venv` function or alias in your current shell.

Comment: The full command with null termination to guard against spaces within the path is: `source "$(find ~/.virtualenvs/ -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 | fzf --read0)"/bin/activate`

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the answer to reflect your comment